# javascript execution continues after return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have below code to validate password matching and email exist ajax call.
The code continues executing after return false.`The emailexist function return 0 if no email id is present and 1 if email id is present.

On form submit

```
<form action="/home" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform();">

function validateemail(){
        var email_id = $("#email").val();
        if(email_id)
        {
           $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/emailexist',
          data: {
           email:email_id,
          },
            success: function (response) {
                      if(response== 1)  
                     {
                       $("#email_status").html("email already exist");
                        return false; 
                     }
                     else if(response == 0){
                     return true;
                }
            }
        });
       }
    function validatepassword()
    {
      var pass = $("#password").val();
     var cofirmpass = $("#confirmpassword").val();
     if(pass != cofirmpass)
      {
        alert("password does not match!");
        return false;
       }
      else{
          return true;
       }
     }
      function validateform()
        {
         if(validatepassword() && validateemail() )
          {
             return true;
           }
         else
           {
             return false;
           }``
           }
      </script>`
```

Comment: Kindly check `preventdefault` functionality.

Comment: That's because you are having an AJAX call. You should call `validateemail` on `blur` event of `#email`

Comment: @MilanChheda : Have done that using $("#email").blur(function(). and use d focus() to ensure control back to email field Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `ajax` and `call back function` !

javascript is a async language and execution happens line by line. But when you pass a function as parameter also known as call back function it executed after the return value come from the server.

That is way in ajax when the data received from the server, the success block executed.